# fatal: unsafe repository on mounted volume

Tags: linux, git

I have a startup mounted volume which contains several git repositories, and I have no idea why, but starting today I can't make git operations in these repositories.

I have this error message:

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('/mnt/sda1/...' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '/mnt/sda1/...'
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is that the whole message or does it print something else as well?

Comment: @user1686 it also prints a command to mark the repository directory path as safe, I've updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu patched git on Apr 8th 2022, so we get a breaking behavior and a security fix without any version update: Follow this link for more updates and solutions: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/760

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the share! I didn't know about this breaking change.
As my volume is mounted at start, the files are indeed owned by root, which is different from the user I logged in.
It seems impossible at now to specify a parent directory for safe repositories, so I'll add each of the repositories for now until there's a solution.